# How to create a favicon for Safari 14?

Tags: html, macos, safari, favicon

I am trying to create favicon for my website (it is not live yet.) Favicon shows on Chrome but not on Safari 14. I have the setting to see websites' favicon turned on. I also tried cleaning Safari's favicon cache. I am using an PNG photo. What shows on Safari is more like a dull/flat representation. [Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVAAE.png) [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKbFW.png)

I tried these websites:

1. https://favicon.io
2. https://www.favicon-generator.org
3. https://realfavicongenerator.net

They all work on Chrome but not on Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it. So, instead of deleting files in ~Library/Safari/Favicon Cache, I had to empty the entire Safari cache from *Develop* menu or using this keyboard shortcut ⌥⌘E

Comment: Congratulations. Please consider accepting your own answer so other users can find answers much more quickly.

Comment: This answer is gold.

Comment: It also worked on Safari 15. It's easy to forget about the empty caches in the developer menu.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have two links,
`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="yourfavicon.png"/>` (for chrome)
`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="yourfavicon.png">` (safari)

Just place both tags in the `<head>` section of your HTML. Here's the link if you want to read more: https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/

Comment: If the favicon shows on chrome, it almost definitely means that OP already knows.

Comment: I have this in my html <head> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"> Still doesn't work.

Comment: Most of the bigger browsers don't support the "sizes" attribute so it's fine if you remove that. Maybe make sure if you put your images in an images folder, to state href="images/favicon.png"

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the contents of the "Favicon Cache" folder, you may need to restart the Safari a couple of times until the contents of that folder created again, eg favicons.db etc.

Then it should open the new favicon. At least, that worked for me.